# Pages - Why dont numbers like 6th format like they do in Word?

Tags: macbook-pro, applications, pages

Whenever I type something that involves order, like 6th or 2nd, in Pages, I want it to be able to do the behavior that Word does, i.e, make the 'th' or the 'nd' part a superscript. Is there any setting to do this? If no, is there any other possible way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually make the "th" superscript.  Highlight the "th", then in the menu bar, select "Format > Font > Baseline > Superscript".  There is also a keyboard shortcut: <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>

Comment: Actually, looking into the menu bar, the shortcut is ⌃⌘+.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Wasn't sure the best way to markup a shortcut.

Comment: You can also add the superscript and subscript buttons to the toolbar, if you find yourself using them frequently.

Answer (score 3):

To have this feature, you need to use Pages 09, where it can be selected in the Autocorrect preferences.  The Pages 5 released in 2013 deletes this feature, along with dozens of others, and has become useless for many purposes.

Comment: Less than useless, actually, Tom. Apple quite idiotically removed some very powerful aspects of these apps in order to make them look and work like their hobbled iOS counterparts. Sad, really.

Comment: According to the App Store, the latest version is 5.5.2, which I have, but I can't find any auto correct preferences.

Comment: Oh wait I checked, Pages 09 is an older version, but I don't want to need to roll back as I have Yosemite. Any other way?

Comment: @eshansingh1 Then I recommend you use Word (or LibreOffice).  I am sure you will regret ever having wasted time creating anything in Pages 5 when you realize the full extent of its defects.